Is there a way to extract the median value data from box plots as CSV using Orange?
I've created a series of box plots based based on geochemical data for geologic units using Orange.
I am attempting to extract the median values (as well as the standard deviation and quantiles) for each unit shown in the box plot as CSV format to further analyze against each other - is there a way to do this using Orange?
Elemental box Plot Example
Thanks,
Formatted box plots, can save and export as graphs, but would like the raw data from these plots.
